# Django count nested ManyToManyField Objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have the following model, which has 3 classes `Project`,`CrawlerProject`,`CrawlerResults`

```
class CrawlerProject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    cralwer_results_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(CrawlerResults,blank=True)
```

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    crawler_project_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(CrawlerProject,blank=True)
```

Here, i want to count the total number of `CrawlerResults` objects are present for all `CrawlerProjects` within individual `Project` object.

```
projects = Project.objects.all().prefetch_related('crawler_project_M2M')
for each_proj in projects:
   total_num_of_crawler_results = each_proj.crawler_project_M2M__cralwer_results_M2M.count() ## count all the crawler_results objects of all crawler_project present in current `project` object.
```

How do I achieve in an efficient way(single query) to get the total count of nested ManyToMany class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
CrawlerProjects =CrawlerProject.objects.all().annotate(CrawlerResults_count=Count('project'))
```

Comment: I m still figure it out a way to add the above annotate in prefetch method since prefetch field is M2M, Do let me know if you know how to add